# Index of the first occurrence of a value in each row

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array and I want to count the number of values (including the *certain value*) until a certain value comes up in each row. If that specific value doesn't exist, return the length of that row. For example:

```
val = 2
arr = np.array([
       [2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 3, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 1]
])
```

I want `array([1, 5, 3])` returned because the first 2 appears in the first row of the first column; doesn't appear in the second row; and appears in the third column of the third row.

How should I do this in a numpythonic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
In [180]: val = 2

In [181]: m = arr == val

In [182]: np.where(m.any(axis=1), m.argmax(axis=1) + 1, arr.shape[1])
Out[182]: array([1, 5, 3], dtype=int64)
```

- getting a mask out of whether equal to `val` or not
- if `any` value is equal in a row, then return the `argmax` of that row, i.e., the index of the first True

  - but add 1 because need to include the value as well
- otherwise, return the number of columns, i.e., `.shape[1]`